# I want to stop awk after 3 loop from file

Tags: awk

I dont know how to stop awk after 3 or 5 or whatever loops.
I have external file output, and there is a 11 records.
I want to stop awk after 3:

I have this:

```
awk ' {rpintf "text " } NR==1,NR==3
{ "print "ending text" } ' /home/file
```

and my output looks like this :

```
text 1 ending text
text 2 ending text
text 3 ending text 
text  ending text 
text  ending text 
text  ending text 
text  ending text 
text  ending text 
text  ending text 
text  ending text
```

how to make it only 3 or specific nubers of loops

Comment: I'm not clear what you wish to do, but does it work if you use `NR<=3` instead of `NR==1,NR==3` ?

Comment: I suggest to copy&paste the code to your question instead of re-typing it. Use the `exit` statement with a suitable condition. (Or the `next` statement.)

Comment: With an `exit`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the range *before* the action: see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info for a brief introduction to awk

```sh
awk 'NR == 1, NR == 3 {print "text", $0, "ending text"}' file
```

Alternatively:

```sh
awk '
    {print "text", $0, "ending text"}
    NR == 3 {exit}
' file
```

If you have the start and end lines in shell variables, you can pass the values to awk like this:

```sh
start_line=6
stop_line=10

awk -v a="$start_line" -v b="$stop_line" '
    NR == a, NR == b {print "text", $0, "ending text"}
' file
```